# ViewBag is null on the second page of PagedList in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I m stuck on this for a while now and will appreciate any help.

The value of ViewBag.SearchTerm is null when I click on the 2 item in the paged list. My List page is present in a partial view (_CentraladdrcdoQuery) as below

```
@using SFRS.GazMatching.Web.DAL
@model IPagedList<CentraladdrcdoQuery>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<div id="results" class="col-md-10">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <table class="table pull-left table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().RecordId)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <table class="table pull-left table-condensed">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RecordId)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 clearfix">

        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Search", new { page, ViewBag.SearchTerm }), new PagedListRenderOptions
    {
        LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<<",
        LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "prev",
        LinkToNextPageFormat = "next",
        LinkToLastPageFormat = ">>",
    })

    </div>
</div>
```

The main search view is

```
@model IPagedList<CentraladdrcdoQuery>

@{     
SearchFormViewModel searchFormViewModel = new SearchFormViewModel();    
 }

 @Html.Partial("_SearchForm",searchFormViewModel)

 <h2>Search Results</h2>

  @Html.Partial("_CentraladdrcdoQuery", Model)
```

and the Search Controller action is

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm, int? page)
    {

        var centraladdrcdoQuerylst=  GetCentraladdrcdoQueryData(searchTerm,page);
        ViewBag.SourceList = GetSourceList();
        ViewBag.SearhTerm = searchTerm;
        return View(centraladdrcdoQuerylst);
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `Search()` and inspect `searchTerm`. Also see your HTML to what gets printed as query string parameters for the URL action where you use `new { page, ViewBag.SearchTerm }`, I think you'll need `new { page, searchTerm = ViewBag.SearchTerm }`.

Comment: You need to go with TempData. TempData is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request (means redirecting from one page to another).